# OS X menu bar gets full on small screen. Any way to scroll?

Tags: macos

My work MacBook Pro's file menu gets full when using a program with many options (like an IDE). This is not a problem when it is attached to an external monitor. But it is a hassle when I am working only on my laptop only.

Is there a utility that will let me scroll the file menu, make it in two layers or just shows the menu icons (clock, VPN, etc) upon hovering?

Any other suggestions (other than replacing my hardware/OS)?

Comment: I remember having used a software that would pop up a copy of the menu bar at your mouse cursor position. Maybe something like that would help? Forgot the name though.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @slhck [MenuPop](http://www.binarybakery.com/menupop.html) or [MenuEverywhere](http://www.binarybakery.com/menueverywhere.html)?

Comment: @Lri MenuPop should actually solve the OP's problem, because it lists the menu elements vertically.

Comment: @slhck Yeah, I should've posted it as an answer immediately. I even had screenshots of both of those apps from a previous answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround would be to use either of these applications that can display the contents of the menu bar in a context menu:

#### [MenuPop](http://www.binarybakery.com/menupop.html)

[image: menupop]

#### [MenuEverywhere](http://www.binarybakery.com/menueverywhere.html)

[image: menueverywhere]

(That *Window Menu Bar* feature could serve as a workaround as well.)

Answer (score 2):

I really really doubt you can do as you suggest/request.

The layout of the Menu bar is fairly fundamental to OSX. I think whatever appearance you get for it is basically what you're stuck with. You can try adjusting some Accessibility settings as perhaps system font changes will help.

However, with the recent release of OSX 10.7 - applications can now run in full screen mode - meaning the menu bar will hide. I think it's (very) remotely possible someone could write an application that essentially hides the menu bar and replaces it with something else. Though I'd like to think that Apple has a bunch of features to prevent this kind of thing as it could be abused by malware quite horrifically.

I hope someone else knows better than I, but my friend, I believe your only real viable solution is to change your hardware..